# Magento Get List of SKUs in Category

Tags: magento

I know Magento categories can be attained with 
    `$categories = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')`
but then how do I get a list of these categories and their respective item SKUs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply require an array containing the category id and an array of skus...

```
$skuArray = array();
$categoryCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
foreach ($categoryCollection as $category) {
    $skuArray[$category->getId()] = $category->getProductCollection()->getColumnValues('sku');
}
```

Alternatively, add a new field to each of the collection objects to contain the skus...

```
$categoryCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
foreach ($categoryCollection as $category) {
    $skus = $category->getProductCollection()->getColumnValues('sku');
    $category->setData('skus', $skus);
}
```

This would be an option if you have further work to do on the collection later in your code and you still need to access the product sku array.

```
foreach($categoryCollection as $category) {
    $categorySkus = $category->getData('skus');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use :

```
$categories = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection');
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $products = $category->getProductCollection();
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $sku[$product->getId()] = $product->getSku();
    }
}
```

I store all the sku in `$sku` as an array. Yours may be different.